# Multiple file upload in powermail Typo3

Tags: typo3, powermail

I have a question about power mail extension multiple file upload in typo3. Is it possible to upload multiple files from different folders in powermail?

Answer (score 3):

The File-Selection-Dialog is from the Operating System of the visitor. So as a website you can not modify the behaviour or functionality of the dialog.